# WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available. how to solve it in kali linux

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, pip

I am getting an error while I'm downloading a module in kali linux.

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt


Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.                                                                  
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/certifi/                                                        
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/certifi/                                                        
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/certifi/                                                        
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/certifi/                                                        
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/certifi/                                                        
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/certifi/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/certifi/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement certifi==2020.4.5.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: none)                                        
ERROR: No matching distribution found for certifi==2020.4.5.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))                                                                                   
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.                                                                  
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

Comment: Beside the point, but if you can't figure this out, Kali might not be the best distribution for you. See [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/117037) on [unix.se].

Answer (score -1):

If using windows then make sure the below three paths are added in Windows environment variable :

1. ....\Anaconda\Library\bin
2. ....\Anaconda\Scripts
3. ....\Anaconda

If not using Anaconda then in place of Anaconda the path where python is installed.